# Mexico entry on japan visa

Tags: japan, mexico

I have a valid visa for Japan. and I want to visit Mexico. Where should I travel first?

I mean if I travel to Japan first, can I fly from Japan to Mexico? Or first do I have to enter Mexico with an unused Japan visa?

Comment: @Rambalac Not according to SkyTeam's TravelDoc. I randomly put in Pakistan for the citizenship. No Mexican visa required if holding a visa for USA, Japan, Schengen, Canada, or UK. Imran, please add your citizenship to your question.

Comment: On a related note: Be aware that direct flights from Asia to Mexico are uncommon and usually expensive; most flights are to the USA or Canada nstead. You may need to transit the USA or Canada to reach Mexico depending on your itinerary.

Answer (score 2):

Holding a valid, unexpired visa from Japan exempts you from the requirement to obtain a visa to visit Mexico. There is no requirement to have actually used the visa; you only need to possess it.

[From the INM](https://www.inm.gob.mx/gobmx/word/index.php/paises-requieren-visa-para-mexico/) (es):

> No requerirá visa mexicana el extranjero que presente alguno de los siguientes documentos:
>
> a)  Documento que acredite residencia permanente en Canadá, Estados Unidos de América, Japón, el Reino Unido de la Gran Bretaña e Irlanda del Norte, cualquiera de los países que integran el Espacio Schengen, así como en los países miembros de la Alianza del Pacífico (Chile, Colombia y Perú).
>
> b)  Visa válida y vigente de Canadá, de los Estados Unidos de América, Japón, el Reino Unido de la Gran Bretaña e Irlanda del Norte o cualquiera de los países que integran el Espacio Schengen.

(and other exemptions not relevant here)

In English, if you have a permanent residence card from Canada, USA, Japan, UK, a Schengen country, or a Pacific Alliance country, or a valid unexpired visa from Canada, USA, Japan, UK, or a Schengen country, then you are exempt for obtaining a visa to visit Mexico.

You still do need a tourist card. Check with your airline if they will provide this for you as part of your airfare or if you need to obtain it separately.